# How to compare two or columns between two different worksheet in excel 2013

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

**Worksheet 1:**

```
 Student Name   Subject   Marks  Percentage

    AAA            A1         60     6
    AAA            A2         65     6.5
    BBB            B1         70     7
```

**Worksheet 2**

```
 Student Name   Subject   Marks  Percentage

    AAA            A1         60     6
    AAA            A2         65     6.5
    AAA            A3         80     8
    AAA            A4         90     9 
    BBB            B1         70     7
```

I need to compare Worksheet 1 & Worksheet 2 with Student,Subject,Mark,Percentage Columns and get the results like below, How do i acheive this?

```
 Student Name   Subject   Marks  Percentage    

    AAA            A3         80     8
    AAA            A4         90     9
```

Worksheet 2 is my original data worksheet 1 is my modified data and i just want to know what is missing in worksheet 1 comparing to worksheet 2?

Comment: Unfortunately your question doesn't make sense. Are you looking for the differences in the Marks between students within Subject type? Or are you looking for unique row entries?

Comment: I need the comparision between worksheet 1 & 2 which is  Student Name   Subject   Marks  Percentage    

    AAA            A3         80     8
    AAA            A4         90     9

Comment: Worksheet 2 is my original data worksheet 1 is my modified data and i just want to know what is missing in worksheet 1 comparing to worksheet 2?

Answer (score 1):

A quick way to see what rows are not in the second sheet is to use some helper columns. Create a concatenated column in each sheet using the formula =A2&B2&C2&D2. ie the value for the first entry in sheet 1 would be AAAA1606. Then in the second helper column, count how many times that entry appears in the other sheet using the formula =countif(Sheet2!E:E,E2). Any time the value is 0, the entry is unique.

Answer (score 1):

Below is bit lengthy VBA code *(experts may disagree this approach)*, this also gives the result what you are looking for, other way is you can use what Chris mentioned above...

```
Public Sub find_mismatch()

Dim base As Object
Dim modified As Object
Dim result As Object

Set base = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Base")
Set modified = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Modified")
Set result = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Result")

' Take each row from "Base" and verify in "Modified" Sheet

Dim i As Integer: i = 1         ' Base sheet row & column
Dim j As Integer: j = 1

Dim x As Integer: x = 1         ' Modified Sheet row & column
Dim y As Integer: y = 1

Dim row As Integer: row = 1     ' Result sheet row & column
Dim col As Integer: col = 1

Do While (Len(Trim(base.Cells(i, j).Value)) > 0)
    Dim b1 As String: b1 = Trim(base.Cells(i, j).Value)
    Dim b2 As String: b2 = Trim(base.Cells(i, (j + 1)).Value)
    Dim b3 As String: b3 = Trim(base.Cells(i, (j + 2)).Value)
    Dim b4 As String: b4 = Trim(base.Cells(i, (j + 3)).Value)
    Dim found As Boolean: found = False
    x = 1
    Do While (Len(Trim(modified.Cells(x, y).Value)) > 0 And (Not found))
        Dim m1 As String: m1 = Trim(modified.Cells(x, y).Value)
        Dim m2 As String: m2 = Trim(modified.Cells(x, (y + 1)).Value)
        Dim m3 As String: m3 = Trim(modified.Cells(x, (y + 2)).Value)
        Dim m4 As String: m4 = Trim(modified.Cells(x, (y + 3)).Value)

        If (b1 = m1 And b2 = m2 And b3 = m3 And b4 = m4) Then
            found = True
        End If
        x = x + 1
    Loop
    If (found = False) Then
        result.Cells(row, col).Value = b1
        result.Cells(row, (col + 1)).Value = b2
        result.Cells(row, (col + 2)).Value = b3
        result.Cells(row, (col + 3)).Value = b4
        row = row + 1
    End If
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Source:
Modified Sheet data:

[image]

Base Sheet data:

[image]

Result Sheet data: (After running the vba macro)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I will check and let you know.